# Best way to measure MongoDB round trip for every Mongo operation in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have Vue + NodeJS + Mongo application deployed in a test environment. Mongo is Atlas T0 tier. There is no traffic, just few testers / developers from time to time. But though I experience quite long waiting times in my web browser. I suspect the shared T0 may cause such delays. But I do not know how to prove it. I would like to see the execution time in Mongo and network round trip time.

I currently [use](https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/blob/master/backend/src/handlers/items/getBlog.js):

```
  logger.debug('Mongo connected');
  const blog = await mongo.getBlog(dbClient, slug, undefined);
  logger.debug('Blog fetched');
```

Which shows me a total execution time. But I do not like such pattern. I prefer to define it once and apply on all Mongo operations.

1. What is the best way to get the required information
2. How to apply it to every mongo operation without repeating the code?

Comment: Use command monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a wrapper for each mongo method:

mongo.js

```
async function findOne(dbClient, collection, query) {
  const start = new Date();
  try {
    const response = await dbClient.db().collection(collection).findOne(query);
    mongoLogger.log({
      time: spent(start),
      operation: 'findOne',
      result: true,
      collection,
      level: 'info',
      message: query,
    });

    return response;
  } catch (err) {
    mongoLogger.log({ time: spent(start), operation: 'findOne', result: false, collection, level: 'info', message: query });
    throw err;
  }
}
```

And winston logger:

```
const mongoCSVFormat = printf((info) => {
  let output = `${info.timestamp},${info.time},${info.operation},${info.result},${(info.collection) ? info.collection : ''},`;
  if (info.message) {
    output += (info.message === Object(info.message)) ? stringify(info.message) : info.message;
  }
  return output;
});

const mongoLogger = createLogger({
  format: combine(appendFullTimestamp(), mongoCSVFormat),
  transports: [
    new transports.File({ filename: 'mongo.log' }),
  ],
});
```

Result is such CSV:

```
2021-03-27 14:19:06:100,24,connect,true,,
2021-03-27 14:19:06:936,2,findOne,true,comments,{"_id":"1f1ptd5v3dc2","parentId":null}
2021-03-27 14:19:06:944,1,findOne,true,comments,{"_id":"1f1ptd65ovqr","parentId":null}
```